# Visual Studio 2010 Load Test Errors

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, mstest, load-testing

I setup a web performance test and it runs fine.  But when I run it in a load test scenario, all the runs fail.  I don't understand why, I'm getting all kinds of errors like:

> 00:03:10   TestList  Scenario1   
>   {POST}    Exception   WebTestException    Context parameter
>   '$HIDDEN1.ctl00$ctl00$PagePlaceholder$Body$Header$hdnKey' not found in
>   test context  Stack   -

Or:

> Extraction Rule Error ExtractHiddenFields 3   No hidden fields were
>   found in the response.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the server returned an error page or a page that is significantly different than the testing tool expected. The tool then failed to find some dynamic data on the page that it needed for a future page - and generated the errors.